# How to do an alphanumeric sorting

Tags: java, mysql, arrays, jakarta-ee, oracle-adf

I am trying to sort the column in a table that has alphanumeric values in it, but I am unable to sort them as intended . some of the values are as below.
QIN XXX. F.1 # 1.1
QIN XXX. F.1 # 1.10
QIN XXX. F.1 # 1.2
QIN XXX. F.1 # 1.20
QIN XXX. 99F.1 # 1.1
QIN XXX. 88F.1 # 1.19
QIN XXX. 72F.1 # 1.1
4444.80
4444.8

the required result should be

QIN XXX. F.1 # 1.1
QIN XXX. F.1 # 1.2
QIN XXX. F.1 # 1.10
QIN XXX. F.1 # 1.20
QIN XXX. 72F.1 # 1.1
QIN XXX. 88F.1 # 1.19
QIN XXX. 99F.1 # 1.1
4444.8
4444.80

Always it should count from left to right, and should check for the numbers as well as the strings and it should order the values. Any information will be helpful.

Thank you

Comment: not sure what sorting criteria you are using, but how is it possible for 1.2 to come before 1.10?

Comment: basically it should treat the numbers like this 1.1>1.2>1.3......1.10 . but I got the same doubt but thats what the requirement says. they were looking for this result. so let me know if atleast we could get the closuer result or any trick that we can use to get to this desired values. and in table there are total 2500 values.

Answer (score 1):

You have several options:
1) Write your own custom sort procedure and use it.

2) Split your string into two number columns. You can do it by creating two transient fields for part before dot and after dot. And then splitting value with groovy. Then you just sort by first column, then by second.

3) Convert your string into the number representation, although you should know limits that numbers after dot can take. So if numbers after dot can have only 3 digits, you should convert it to something like:
1.001 instead of 1.1, 1.01 instead of 1.10 and so on.

ps: its not really adf or java question, its common in any language.